# why jQuery Mobile not recommended for enterprise applications

Tags: jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

In many of the SO questions related to  jQuery Mobile vs other frameworks like Sencha,the former does not get recommended for enterprise centric applications.What are the specific reasons why jQuery mobile is not recommended?

Answer (score 1):

For several reasons, the first would be speed. Sencha is a highly optimized framework compared to jQuery and the resulting code base is more efficient. You can get jQuery to a decent speed but it requires much more optimisation on your part. JQuery you use a combination of HTML & JavaScript whereas With Sencha it is mostly just JavaScript hence the speed difference.

A second reason would be scalability, for large enterprise applications Sencha is much better and more modular, if your application is large and you need to extend it Sencha's MVC framework allows you to build add-on parts easily by adding new views, models and stores. JQuery does not have a decent MVC framework.

The Sencha framework also provides a modern and simple way of connecting to data services...such as the new Windows Azure connection tools etc. jQuery this is possible but not as fully featured.

Hope that helps,

:-)